# Filtering index of true values into lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to write a function that will identify values in a list of lists that are 5 times larger than values at the same index in other list (in other words, within a row the function identifies the largest value and determines if that value is 5 times larger than all other values in the row) . After doing this, I would like the function to return a new list of lists, each list containing the index of values for which the function was true in the larger list. To clarify, for example, in a list like this:

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]
```

I would want an output like this:

```
filtered = [[], [0], [1,2]]
```

because the first list in samples_avg has no values for which it is `true`, the second is true at index 0, and the last is true at indexes 1 and 2.

to do this I have written:

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]

 def check(samples_avg):
    filtered = []
    #Find largest Value in row
    maxval = [max(x) for x in zip(*samples_avg)]
    #Determine if it is 5x larger than all other values in the row
    maxlist = [(r >= (m/5)) for row in samples_avg for r, m in zip(row, maxval)]

    #find index in each list for which maxlist is true
    filtered = [z for z, y in zip(samples_avg, maxlist) if y == True]


    print (maxval)
    print (maxlist)
    print (filtered)

out:
  maxval = [15000, 144, 45]
  maxlist = [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True]
  filtered = []
```

Both `maxval` and `maxlist` work fine at finding values that are true. However, it is the final step of finding the indexes which are true in each list is confusing me. What I have written for `filtered` returns an empty list.

Comment: in `12,1,144`, 12 is not 5 time larger than other values.

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh I think there might be a misunderstanding here. 12 is returned as `False` because it is smaller than 144, which is returned as `True` because it is at least 5 times the size of 12 and 4. there is no value 1 at index 1, so the function does not compare 1 to the values at index 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood the problem right. The "trick" is to store all needed indexes within the maximum value. We use tuple for this, with value on first index, from which array is this value as second index and which iteration are we on as third index:

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]

out = [[] for _ in samples_avg]
for idx, v in enumerate(zip(*samples_avg)):
    m = max((val, i, idx) for i, val in enumerate(v))
    if all(val * 5 < m[0] for i, val in enumerate(v) if i != m[1]):
        out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[], [0], [1, 2]]
```